# A characterization of root systems via their intersections with halfspaces

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, root-systems, symmetry

In a recent [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10469v1) I obtained a nice characterization of root systems as a side product.
I can imagine that this was known before, and that a source for this statement can shorten the proof of my main result.

> **Question:** Can you point me to a source, or a simple proof of the facts I list below?

---

In the following, let $R\subset \Bbb R^d$ be finite and centrally symmetric, i.e. $R=-R$.

**Some definitions**:

- $R$ is a *root system* if for all $r\in R$ the set $R$ is invariant w.r.t. reflection on the hyperplane $r^\bot$.
- A *half* (or *semi-star* in the preprint) is the intersection of $R$ with a halfspace, so that the intersection contains exactly half the elements of $R$. (see figure)
- The *norm* of a half is the norm of the sum of the vectors it contains.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

The two characterizations now read as follows:

> **Result.**
>
> 1. (Corollary 5.1) All halves of $R$ are congruent (i.e. they are related by orthogonal transformations) if and only if $R$ is a root system.
> 2. (Theorem 5.2) If all vectors in $R$ are of the same length, and all halves of $R$ are of the same norm, then $R$ is a root system.

In point 1. the direction that proofs that $R$ is a root system is the non-trivial part.

Comment: That's a nice result!  I had a quick look, but, without tracing the chain of implications all the way back, it's not apparent:  do you use a classification result, or is this from first principles?  (Also, you're missing a period at the end of Section 5.)

Comment: @LSpice Thank you! I would say it is from first principles, just with a detour over zonotopes, so probably using some well-known facts about polytopes (but no classification). In particular, the classification of root systems plays no role for this characterization.